# Gnuplot color filled contour plot from my ascii data

Tags: gnuplot, contour

I have an ascii data file with ~30 columns of data. I would like to make a x vs. y plot (columns 1 and 2) and use column 17 for making the filled color contour plot. If I do:

```
set pm3d map
splot "datafile" u 1:2:17
```

then I get a message saying: Warning, Single isoline (scan) is not enough for a pm3d plot.
       Hint: Missing blank lines in the data file?
My datafile does not contain any linebreaks. So line 1 contains 30 columns for particle 1, line 2 contains 30 columns for particle 2 ....etc. Is there an easy way to get round this if my file does not contain linebreaks?

Comment: Do the x and y-values form a regular grid and are the x / y values in increasing order and grouped? Or do you know more about the structure. In that case you could use e.g. `awk` to insert appropriate line breaks with `splot '< awk '{...}' datafile'`. Or you could use `set dgrid3d` with an appropriate interpolation algorighm and grid size; `pm3d` does interpolation in any case.

Comment: The x and y-values are not in increasing order or grouped in any way i.e. they are random (and range from -0.5 to +0.5). The ordering is done via column 19 which is the id of the particles. So in the first line, the 19th column has value 0, in the 2nd line, the 19th column has value = 1 corresponding to the 2nd particle etc... @Christoph

Comment: To plot a pm3d surface you need a regular grid. For non-gridded data, like you have, you must create a regular grid with `set dgrid3d` (see the documentation for available parameters and http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.6/scatter.html for demos, although not with pm3d.)